# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am having a very strange issue. Some of the images on my site (randomly) are failing to load with cloudfront with a 502 error. Most of the images on my site work fine.

What's even more strange is that on debugging the content type is shown as text/html whereas the filename is a .jpg, so it should have been treated as an image..

What's even more puzzling is that if I connect with VPN, the images load fine. It feels like being an issue with my NGINX server being too fast and not integrating properly with cloudfront?

```
  Request URL: https://xyz.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Mondrian.jpg
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 502 
    Remote Address: [xyz:21]:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    content-length: 1033
    content-type: text/html
    date: Tue, 21 Mar 2023 10:05:42 GMT
    server: CloudFront
    x-cache: Error from cloudfront
    :authority: xyz.cloudfront.net
    :method: GET
    :path: /wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Mondrian.jpg
    :scheme: https
    accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
    referer: https://www.example.com/
    sec-ch-ua: "Brave";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
    sec-fetch-dest: image
    sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
    sec-fetch-site: cross-site
    sec-gpc: 1
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I have voted to close your question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

I would somehow try to force in code:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

To avoid any auto-detection problems.